# Looping through xml with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, loops, each

I'm trying to get multiple bandnames after another using an each loop but all i'm getting is the final name from the loop. can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong.

XML structure:

```
<resultsPage>
  <results>
    <event type="concert">
      <performance displayName="bandname1"></performance>
      <performance displayName="bandname2"></performance>
      <performance displayName="bandname3"></performance>
    </event>
  </results>
</resultsPage>
```

ajax:

```javascript
$.ajax({
    url: 'xml/timeline.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find('resultsPage results event').each(function(){
            var type = $(this).attr('type');
            var band = $(this).find('performance artist').each(function(){
                name = $(this).attr('displayName');
            })

            $('.timeline ul').append(
                '<li>A '+type+' played by '+name+'</li>'
            );

        });
    },
    error: function(){
        $('.timeline').text('Failed to get feed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `name` variable in each iteration. Change to:

```
$(data).find('resultsPage results event').each(function(){
    var type = $(this).attr('type');
    var band = $(this).find('performance artist');
    var length = $(band).length;
    $(band).each(function(index, element){
        name += $(this).attr('displayName');
        if (index < length-1) {
           name += ", ";
        }
    });

    $('.timeline ul').append(
        '<li>A '+type+' played by '+name+'</li>'
    );

});
```

Comment: then your getting something like this: A concert played by bandname1, A concert played by bandname2. but i want something like: A concert played by bandname1, bandname 2, bandname3

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note the += operator and the concatenated ", ".